# Sql where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a stored procedure where I am passing a value to be used in the select statement in the where clause.

If the value that I am passing is NULL, I do not want it to be part of that portion of the where clause where it is used. In the example below, variable2 is the variable I am passing to the stored procedure and using in the sql statement but if @variable2 is NULL, I do not want to use variable2= @val1 in the where clause. Example:

```
select Field1, Field2 from tbl1
where variable2= @val1
and ID = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
where (@val1 is null or variable2 = @val1)
and ID = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Field1, Field2 from tbl1 
where (variable2= @val1 or @val1 is null)
and ID = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select Field1, Field2 from tbl1
where (@val1 IS NULL or variable2 = @val1)
and ID = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause should have the column on the left side, and that could possibly be the case but you are calling it `variable2`.  This would work, given specific parameters:

```
select Field1, Field2
from tbl1
where yourColumn = 
case
    when @param1 is null
    then @param2
end
```

I have used a generic field name and parameter names, but you should get the idea.